# Вывод текста в текстовом поле

Tags: javascript, html

Что нужно поправить в коде что б в текстовое поле выводилось не только номер групы а и имя которое ввелив окне?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Реєстрація</title>
<script>
  function reg(obj)
  {var s=window.prompt("Введіть ваше ім’я","")
  obj.value=s;
  
  alert("Ви ввели: "+s+".");
  }
  function btnClick2()
          {
              if(document.forma.name[0].checked)
              {document.forma.text.value="Ви вибрали групу: 401."}
              if(document.forma.name[1].checked)
              {document.forma.text.value="Ви вибрали групу: 402."}
              if(document.forma.name[2].checked)
              {document.forma.text.value="Ви вибрали групу: 406."}
          }
          </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p><strong>Метод <em>prompt</em> для об’єкта window</strong></p> <form name="forma">
      <h3>Оберіть номер групи:</h3>
      <input type="radio" name="name" id="sp1" value="sp1">401<br>
      <input type="radio" name="name" id="sp2" value="sp2">402<br>
      <input type="radio" name="name" id="sp3" value="sp3">406<br>
      <input type="button" value="Реєстрація" onclick="reg(forma);btnClick2()"><br><br>
      <input type="text" name="text" size="43">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если по быстрому то примерно так:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Реєстрація</title>
    <script>
    let s = '';
      function reg(obj) {
        s = window.prompt("Введіть ваше ім’я", "")

        alert("Ви ввели: " + s + ".");
      }

      function btnClick2() {
        if (document.forma.name[0].checked) {
          document.forma.text.value = `${s} Ви вибрали групу: 401.`
          
        }
        if (document.forma.name[1].checked) {
          document.forma.text.value = `${s} Ви вибрали групу: 402.`
        }
        if (document.forma.name[2].checked) {
          document.forma.text.value = `${s} Ви вибрали групу: 403.`
        }
        
      }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p><strong>Метод <em>prompt</em> для об’єкта window</strong></p>
    <form name="forma">
      <h3>Оберіть номер групи:</h3>
      <input type="radio" name="name" id="sp1" value="sp1">401<br>
      <input type="radio" name="name" id="sp2" value="sp2">402<br>
      <input type="radio" name="name" id="sp3" value="sp3">406<br>
      <input type="button" value="Реєстрація" onclick="reg(forma);btnClick2()"><br><br>
      <input type="text" name="text" size="43">
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое